# What is an association bonus?

Tags: discussion

### Background

I was recently searching for a question to answer, and I came across this one question with a score of -2, and I noticed **this was that particular person's only question,** and he had a some sort of **reputation bonus of 100.** At first I thought he might've won a bounty. Although, he **also had not answered any questions, either.** Then I was sorta confused, so I decided to check his **reputation changes,** and I found this:

[image: Yesterday: +100; today: +1]

So apparently he/she won some sort of "association bonus".

### Question

> ***What is an association bonus?***

Comment: [Duplicate on Meta Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/141648/350567)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the FAQ on Meta Stack Exchange: [What is the association bonus?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/141648/350567)

> The Association Bonus is a block award of 100 reputation granted on all of a user's network profiles, including ones created after the bonus is awarded. It is awarded when a user's account has **accumulated 200+ reputation on any one site** in the network, provided they have at least two network accounts. This bonus gives users who have shown some basic understanding of how the Stack Exchange system works a boost past the initial site restrictions on sites where they have low reputation.

It can be 100% sure that the user has just passed the 200 reputation milestone on another site, which grants them an extra 100 reputation on all sites. It's a very common phenomenon.

It's also the same reason why I have 101 rep here instead of 1 - even though I have zero post on the main site (Astronomy) - because I have more than 200 elsewhere.